# How do I send a server-side app request using the C# FacebookSdk?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, facebook-graph-api, request, facebook-c#-sdk

I'm looking to send a severside app-request (as documented here https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/464/) through the [C# Facebook Sdk](http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/). Anyone have some sample code or documentation of the process?

Answer (score 1):

You can perform an app-generated request with the following code:

```
var client = new FacebookClient("app_access_token");
var parameters = new {
   message = "My Message",
   data = "Some Data"
};

dynamic result = client.Post("/user_id/apprequests, parameters);
```

If you want to do a user generated request, you must do that on the client with the JavaScript SDK.